# The difference between opening 'cmd.exe' directly or via 'qprocess' pyside

Tags: python, environment-variables, pyside, qprocess

I tried opening the python file via cmd.exe, when I opened the python file via cmd.exe which I opened directly in "C: \ Windows \ System32 \ cmd.exe", it went smoothly. but when I open the python file via cmd.exe in qprocess there is an error like this "ImportError:"

[image]

I have tried opening cmd.exe through several methods like this:

- os.startfile ("C: \ Windows \ System32 \ cmd.exe")
- process.startDetached ('cmd.exe')

I want to open a python file via qprocess and its env

Comment: A screenshot of part of an error message with all the information except that part of the error message wiped out isn't very helpful. Can you provide the full text of the actual error message? Apart from that, how / why do you want to open Python through qprocess - what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That is a environment variable's related, I think. Take a look at them , in cmd you can run `set`, then try to set them a way if not equal (run cmd from start menu/run cmd when runs with your code)...

Comment: thank you for helping. maybe i should set env beforehand :)